# How to replace two eval() in a comparison

Tags: javascript

In the following snippet of code:

```
    case "lessthan": {
        if (eval(firstvalue) >= eval(secondvalue)) {
            compare = " should be less than ";
            compReturn = false;
        }
        break;
```

I would like to remove the eval() parts for more efficient code, where the contents are expected to be numbers. I've read other similar questions which I don't understand, so I hope this is a simple case!
I'm starting with

```
     if parseFloat(firstvalue) >= parseFloat(secondvalue) {
```

but having read so much about eval() I have a feeling I'm missing something.

Comment: Note that the `if` statements needs its own parenthesis around the `parseFloat()` comparison, which are missing from your 2nd snippet.

Comment: What is `firstvalue`?

Comment: Without seeing your specific use case, I'm going to have to go with `if (firstvalue >= secondvalue) {`

Comment: @dave `firstvalue` and `secondvalue` are probably strings.

Comment: Sorry for the omission, they are variables for strings expected to be integers.

Comment: @user3536838: if they are integers - why do you use `parseFloat`?

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try it; I've found parseInt on W3C, but it doesn't explain the ,10) you've added to each side.

Comment: The bad news is, I need to ask another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting int values, you can use `parseInt`, and you should also check the return value to ensure you are getting a usable number back.

```
case "lessthan": {
    var a = parseInt(firstvalue, 10), // 10 specifies base, so inputs aren't
        b = parseInt(secondvalue, 10); // interpreted as hex, octal, etc
    if ( isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) ) { 
        // TODO a parse failed, handle your error condition
    }
    else if (a >= b) {
        compare = " should be less than ";
        compReturn = false;
    }
    break;
```