# Replacing eval() for object properties in a comparison

Tags: javascript

Having got a comprehensive answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24876942/3536838), I found that the variables concerned actually represent object properties.
How does this affect things? Can I no longer replace this

```
if (eval(firstvalue) >= eval(secondvalue)) {
```

with this

```
var a = parseInt(firstvalue, 10), b = parseInt(secondvalue, 10);
if (a >= b) {  // abridged version of the answer linked above.
```

Comment: And what does these object properties look like

Comment: I would expect them to be integers, but someone told me they won't respond to parsing in the same way as strings.

Comment: If you use `parseInt` on a number, it first converts the number to a string and then parses it. So if you use 10 as the radix, you get the same number. So where's the problem? What exactly do you mean by those object properties?

Comment: All I have is        firstvalue = objValue.value;

Comment: Well then just parse it if you are not completely sure it's an integer.

Comment: I'm not so great with objects, so not sure of this content; it's from a form validation script, if that helps.